# Julia worker process has error loading ZLIB shared library, while local process works fine. How can I get the worker process to work too?

Tags: julia

I'm using Metalhead (https://github.com/FluxML/Metalhead.jl) to do some image recognition stuff. I can run the `Metalhead.preprocess("filename.jpg")` which works fine in the interactive interpreter. As far as I'm aware Metalhead calls ImageMagick behind the scenes, which is using ZLIB and other libraries that are downloaded and linked specifically for ImageMagick. It shouldn't be using the system ZLIB. I can unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH before starting Julia and it builds and runs fine.

When I have a remote worker try to do `Metalhead.preprocess(...)` though, even on the same path, I end up with errors:

```
From worker 2:     in zipin zipError encountered while loading "/tmp/5b7e9947-ddc0-4b3f-9b55-0d8042f74170.jpeg".
From worker 2:    Fatal error:in zip
From worker 2:    InitError: error compiling __init__: could not load library "/mnt/username/.julia/packages/ImageMagick/vMfoS/deps/usr/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.so"
From worker 2:    /lib64/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found (required by /mnt/username/.julia/packages/ImageMagick/vMfoS/deps/usr/lib/libpng16.so.16)
```

Does a remote worker process start up with a reset environment, and still use LD_LIBRARY_PATH which might be pointing to my system ZLIB before the one downloaded by ImageMagick? Is there a way to force it to not be set on these spawned processes?

Answer (score 0):

As usual, I figured it out shortly after deciding to ask here:

Instead of just starting up after unsetting LD_LIBRARY_PATH, I specifically set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the lib folder ImageMagick downlodas. After doing that everything seems to be working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When using Julia libraries in multi-process environments it is usually good to load them like this:

```
using Metalhead
@everywhere using Metalhead
```

In this way you avoid the occasional situation where several workers try to compile the same library simultaneously.

While I understand that you had a different issue - this is the most common answer to questions such us "It worked on single process but does not work when using parallel workers".